# Access of previous iteration variable in Matlab optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to minimize a function using fmincon in Matlab, but in evaluating my constraint function i need the value of the variable from the previous iteration.

My question is : how do i access the value of the variable in each iteration?

Comment: you might improve the quality of this post by adding in a bit of the relevant code or what you have tried already.

Comment: I doubt you really need that in your constraint. Anyway when converged to the optimal solution, you can assume `x(k)=x(k-1)` where `k` is the iteration number.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the optional output function 'OutputFcn' that can be defined in the optimisation options. This function is called after each iteration and is passed the current value of the optimization vector

options = optimset('OutputFcn', @CustomOutputFcn)

```
function stop = CustomOutputFcn(x,optimValues,state)
stop = false;
% Store x to previously defined global variable XPreviousStep
global XPreviousStep
XPreviousStep = x;
end
```

Now you can access XPreviousStep in your constraint function. You can utilize guidata if you don't like global variables.